# password in md5 format in mongodb+nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, md5

I want to save password in md5 format
can anyone tell me how it is possible in mongodb?
I have used bcrypt and salt but the format of my password is not md5

Comment: You can use crypto library https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto

Comment: Perhaps I'm misinterpreting your question, but: *please, please, please* don't store your passwords as MD5. [It has long since been proven to be insecure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Security), and even setting that aside, [it's not well suited to password hashing](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/52461/how-weak-is-md5-as-a-password-hashing-function). Salted bcrypt is a much better solution.

Answer (score 1):

In NodeJS you can use Crypto library doing this

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

var password = 'my Password';
var hash = crypto.createHash('md5').update(password).digest('hex');
```

You can have more informations about this method here [crypto.createHash](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createhash_algorithm)

Comment: using this library $2a$10$t6TXdREGlrEpYTs/u/Ub1OWvFOR1BmWfVe8MqWSJYhYAOdCYYHUrm getting this password

Comment: It's strange i just test it and get md5 format '329670c3265b6ccd392e622733e9772f'

Comment: can you tell me where to right in code??? and var password = 'my Password'; is the static value you are passing?

Comment: @kalpita var password is the password passed by the user. 'my Password' is an example of a password passed

Comment: getting the password in $2a$10$ZCRAvtjXXW.SYoV7hbAEkuvZtTHO5TCyFqEbleqaujniM3Fa4g9O. in this format only instead of md5

Comment: can you share your whole code of login so that it will be easy to test

Comment: I don't have any whole code of login, im passing the password from the user instead of 'myPassword'